# Reference outer namespace function in inner anonymous function

Tags: typescript, reference, namespaces

I need to access some method in a typescript class from an **inner function**. The inner function obviously has a different *namespace*, so just using `this.outerMethod()` doesn´t work.

So I used a variable to reference the outer 'this':

```
let ref = this;
...
function innerFunction(){
   ref.outerMethod();
}
```

but it just says 'self is undefined'.

On top of that, the outer method I need to call sometimes refers to class properties, which then are also in the outer namespace.

What do I have to do to successfully reference the outer method inside an inner function?

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax instead:

```js
let innerFunction = ()=>
{
    ref.outerMethod();
}
```